# Part not deleting idk why nothing happens

Tags: lua, roblox

game:WORKSPACE:Part:Destroy()

what is the issue

I want the part to destroy there is only one part I don't know what the issue is, if someone could help me, I'd be grateful, probably get the point by looking at the script too.

Comment: using colons between elements in the path makes the game think you are trying to call functions. Use periods : `game.Workspace.Part:Destroy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:Workspace` doesn't exist, instead try to replace it by

`.Workspace`. With these changes the script should looks like this : `game.Workspace.Part:Destroy()`.

Hope this help !